# Finding sequence of closed orbits in 4th order dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

Consider the system $$\dot{x}=y, \qquad \dot{y}=xw^2-GM/{x^2}, \qquad \dot{z}=w, \qquad \dot{w}=-2yw/{x}$$ that represent a satellite in orbit where x= radius (distance from earth) y= radius velocity. z=angle and w=angle velocity.

i tried to solve it with matlab and ode45 with r=42200000 starting point.
And i get what it seems to be a periodic solution, the radius oscillates , and the angle keep going, and this is for diverse starting point. At some point the radius start to diverge.

how i explained it is that in a certain area i have a periodic solution. after i'm to far away from earth so i don't have the gravity keeping me there.

is there a way to demonstrate/visualize those closed orbit? like a phase plane portrait or some kind of poincare maps?

Comment: Is that not just the Kepler laws? If you have only one body in a central field, or a 2-body problem, then there is no "too far away", you get always periodic orbits if the velocity is not too large. You will have to fine-tune component-wise error tolerances so that the step size controller gives all components equal influence. Or in another way, find a renormalization of the system so that all components are of comparable size. Otherwise the error in the "small" components like the velocity will be overly large.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Hi, i think it's the kepler laws, i took it from here: https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/mavt/dynamic-systems-n-control/idsc-dam/Lectures/System-Modeling/Slides_HS16/Lecture12.pdf , i'm doing a nonlinear control class so i need to perform analysis and then a control on it.

Comment: For your calculation you get sensible values if you measure lengths in multiples of 10 000 km and time in hours. So your orbit is at about 4 length units and its speed at about 20 length units per hour

Comment: Your system is an energy conserving system. `ode45` is not an energy conserving integration scheme. Not knowing exactly what you're plotting or exactly how you're using `ode45`, you may be observing this phenomenon. `ode45` may still be adequate for your purposes if you specify the correct tolerances and don't integrate for too long. Otherwise you may want to look into [symplectic integration schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator) that are designed for these types of problems.

Comment: Also, what have you tried with respect to plotting the phase space of this problem?